# Creating image table in python

Tags: python, image

Here is my problem: I have n images. They have the same width and height, they are png. I want to make an image(png) that contains a table out of them that have 5x(n/5) images in it by simply putting them next to each other.

I never tried creating images in Python, so could you help me what package and functions to use?

Answer (score 7):

It seems like this is so trivial everyone knows how to vote down but no one knows the answer, right?

OK, so the package is Image, to create a canvas we need Image.new(colour_mode, size=(x,y), colour)
to put an image into this image we need
Image.paste(image, (left, up, right, down))

Thanks a lot for nothing.

Comment: You are on Stack overflow; if the question is not interesting enough, people just downvote because [reasons]. Since there is no accountability when you downvote, to avoid [put reasons here], that's what most people do, instead of being helpful or move on.
Regarding your question: it is not trivial and require you to merge those images; you can use OpenCV for image manipulation for example; which allow you to stitch images together.